# initialize a union array at declaration

Tags: c, arrays, sse, initializer, unions

I'm trying to initialize the following union array at declaration:

```
typedef union { __m128d m;  float f[4]; } mat;
mat m[2] = { {{30467.14153,5910.1427,15846.23837,7271.22705},
{30467.14153,5910.1427,15846.23837,7271.22705}}};
```

But I'getting the following error:

```
matrix.c: In function ‘main’:
matrix.c:21: error: incompatible types in initialization
matrix.c:21: warning: excess elements in union initializer
matrix.c:21: warning: (near initialization for ‘m[0]’)
matrix.c:21: warning: excess elements in union initializer
matrix.c:21: warning: (near initialization for ‘m[0]’)
matrix.c:21: warning: excess elements in union initializer
matrix.c:21: warning: (near initialization for ‘m[0]’)
matrix.c:21: error: incompatible types in initialization
matrix.c:21: warning: excess elements in union initializer
matrix.c:21: warning: (near initialization for ‘m[1]’)
matrix.c:21: warning: excess elements in union initializer
matrix.c:21: warning: (near initialization for ‘m[1]’)
matrix.c:21: warning: excess elements in union initializer
matrix.c:21: warning: (near initialization for ‘m[1]’)
```

Comment: Side note, placing SSE vectors (`__m128`) inside a union will absolutely destroy any optimization you were hoping to get from SSE / SIMD. These types need to remain unmolested in order for the compiler to generate code that operates on them in the XMM registers. I realize this question is 7 years old, but I stumbled upon it having just learned this lesson the hard way.

Answer (score 14):

Quoting [this page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/strin.htm):

> With C89-style initializers, structure members must be initialized in the order declared, and only the first member of a union can be initialized.

So, either put the `float` array first, or if possible use C99 and write:

```
mat m[2] = { { .f = { /* and so on */ } }, /* ... */ };
```

The important thing being the `.f`.

Comment: There needs to be a set of braces around the entire `.f = { ... }` expression as well.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks, typo. Fixed.

Comment: The cleaner solution was moving the float declaration to the first position. This makes unnecessary use ".f" and it compiles without errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to indicate which union field you are initializing.  Try using this syntax:

```
mat m[2] = {
    {.f = {30467.14153,5910.1427,15846.23837,7271.22705}},
    {.f = {30467.14153,5910.1427,15846.23837,7271.22705}}
};
```

This successfully compiled for me, without any warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change members:

```
typedef union {
    float f[4];
    __m128d m;
} mat;
mat m[2] = { { {30467.14153,5910.1427,15846.23837,7271.22705},
               {30467.14153,5910.1427,15846.23837,7271.22705} } };
```

If you initialize union without member specification like .f = { ... } then first member of union is initialized.