# Nested braces and designated Initializers

Tags: c

Why I need the nested braces to compile this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef union TEST TEST;

union TEST {
    int type;
    char *things;
 };


int main () {

    TEST test[] = {1, 2, .things = NULL}; // Compile time error

    TEST test[] = {1, 2, {.things = NULL}}; // Works, but I didn't check at run time

    return 0;
}
```

Why the first assignment doesn't works?
Why the inner braces are needed?
Are there any way to work in the first assignment? Without the inner braces?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [initialize a union array at declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558390/initialize-a-union-array-at-declaration). See the first [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11558466/519383).

Comment: I guess not, I'm using C99 already, I'm wondering why the inner braces are needed...

Comment: There are no compound literals in this question.

Comment: Sorry, It was...I'm using compound literals in my code, I removed it when I was asking to make the question simplest, I will try to change the title, thanks.

Comment: You already did, haha Thanks, I will check your answer soon and I'll leave a feedback, give me a little time to read and to understand, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In summary: `{1, 2, .things = NULL}` attempts to initialize an element of the array `test` that is named `things`, but the array does not have an element named `things`, so this is invalid. In contrast, `{1, 2, {.things = NULL}}` attempts to initialize a member of the second element of the array that is named `things`, and the second element of the array is a union that does have a member named `things`, so this is valid.

Per C 2011 (N1570) 6.7.9 17:

> Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated *current object*. When no designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union. In contrast, a designation causes the following initializer to begin initialization of the subobject described by the designator. Initialization then continues forward in order, beginning with the next subobject after that described by the designator.

There is more in subsequent paragraphs about how the *current object* is handled, but this is enough for now. In the brace-enclosed initializer list, `1` is a simple initializer; it does not have any designations. So it initializes a subobject of the array, which is an array element. Similarly, `2` initializes another element. Then we have `.things = NULL`. This does have a designator, `.things`.

According to the quoted paragraph, this designator, `.things` causes initialization of the subobject described by `.things`. But there is nothing in the array that is designated by `.things`. It is only an array with indexed elements, designated by `[index]`. It does not have any members designated by `.thigns`. So there is an error.

In the second list, where additional braces are used, paragraph 20 applies:

> If the aggregate or union contains elements or members that are aggregates or unions, these rules apply recursively to the subaggregates or contained unions. If the initializer of a subaggregate or contained union begins with a left brace, the initializers enclosed by that brace and its matching right brace initialize the elements or members of the subaggregate or the contained union.…

In this case, `{.things = NULL}` begins with a left brace. This says that the initializers contained within the braces initialize the current object of the larger list. So they are initializing the next element of the array (the element with index 2). Any element of the array is a union with a member named `things`, so `.things` does designate a subobject in it, and this syntax is acceptable.

Comment: Yeah, I think I got: I was using designated initializer in the wrong way, I was trying to access the union member, but the compiler was waiting for the index of array test, not the .things member of union...

Said that...Do you have any idea how to accomplish the first try of assignment without the inner braces?

Comment: The weird part is the gcc compile error:
teste.c:14:5: error: field name not in record or union initializer

With record, it want to means array? I don't know, english is not my speak language.

Comment: TEST *test = (TEST[]){1, 2, [3].things = NULL}; // Now it works!

Do you know any way to accomplish that without being stuck on the index position, you know the `[3]` part...sorry my bad english, I guess you understood.

Comment: @drigoSkalWalker: You probably want `[2].things = NULL`, not `[3]`; the elements are indexed 0, 1, 2. I am not aware of any way to initialize via `.things` other than using an index or nested braces, except that you can use a compound literal. It involves braces, but in a different way (technically): `{1, 2, (TEST){.things = NULL}}`.

Comment: My mistake.

Yeah, at first, before you had edited the title of my question, I was using compound literal, but making another array like (TEST[]){1, 2, .things = NULL} so, I was falling in the same problem, but now I understand why, Did you read the standard? To know all those things..

Thank you, have a good day!

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you don't need inner braces on the first two elements is an odd detail in the syntax for initializer lists, which allows a union to be initialized as its first element. I would suggest using braces and designation for *all* the initializers in the list, not just `.things`.

Comment: For me, doesn't make sense the use of inner braces...I'm still in doubt

Comment: Consider: What if `TEST` were a struct instead of a union? The rules are nearly the same between the two. Would you initialize a struct containing an `int` and a `char*` by setting it to `3`?

Comment: I got your point, it does make sense with struct, but I don't feel the same with union..

Comment: Allowing the braces to be left out for unions would lead to ambiguities when a struct contained union types.

Comment: I appreciate your time Sneftel, but the point is, you answered, in short, like that: "Just put the inner braces, and it will work fine...". But I'm searching why, you know, why is this necessary, why the first try doesn't works, I hope you understand...Thank for your time again.

Comment: Because the syntactic rules don't allow it. They can't allow it, not without making the language ambiguous.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that was because some rule, but you didn't explain why, besides that Eric Postpischil gave a excellent answer. We both increase our knowledge thanks to him.