# number of braces for parameter list in designated initializer

Tags: c++, initialization, c++20

I am currently struggling with number of braces in the parameter list even if I use `C++2a` designated initializer.

I have some nested structs as example:

```
#include <string>
#include <optional> 

struct Base
{
    std::string name;
};

struct KL: public Base
{
    int p1;
    int p2;
};

struct FFA: public Base
{
    int pp1;
    int pp2;
    int pp3;
};

struct Spur
{
    std::optional< KL >              kl;
    std::optional< FFA >             ffa ;
};

struct Config
{
    std::string s;
    int i1;
    int i2;
    Spur spur;

    Config(
        const std::string& _s,
        int _i1,
        int _i2,
        const Spur& _spur
        ): s{_s},i1{_i1},i2{_i2},spur{_spur}{}
};

class Signal
{
    public:
        Signal( const Config& ) {}
};

struct A { int i; };
struct B { std::string s; };
struct X { A a; B b; };

int main()
    Spur s1{   .kl= {{ "XYZ", 1,2 }}}; // works! gcc+clang but clang warns "suggest braces around initialization of subobject"
    Spur s2{   .kl=  { "XYZ", 1,2 }} ; // fails! could not convert '{"XYZ", 1, 2}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::optional<KL>'
    Spur s3{ { .kl=  { "XYZ", 1,2 }}}; // works gcc! clang fails: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::optional<KL>' 


    Config c1{ "ABC", 1,2 , {{ .kl=std::nullopt }}}; // works gcc, clang fails no matching constructor for initialization of 'Config'
    Config c2{ "ABC", 1,2 , {  .kl=std::nullopt }} ; // works for gcc and clang

    Signal si1{ {"ABC", 1,2 , {{ .kl = std::nullopt     }} }}; // gcc ok, clang fails: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Signal'
    Signal si2{ {"CDE", 3,4 , {{ .kl = KL{ "XYZ", 1,2 } }} }}; // gcc ok, clang fails: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Signal'
    Signal si3{ {"CDE", 3,4 , {{ .kl =   { "XYZ", 1,2 } }} }}; // gcc ok, clang fails: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Signal'
    Signal si4{ {"CDE", 3,4 , {  .kl = KL{ "XYZ", 1,2 }  } }}; // clang & gcc ok
    Signal si5{ {"CDE", 3,4 , {  .kl =   { "XYZ", 1,2 }  } }}; // gcc& clang fail: no matching function for call to 'Signal::Signal(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'

    X x{ .b={"Hallo"  }}; 
    X x2{ .a={1} };
```

My question is: 
When I need another set of braces around the parameter set in the initializer list?

I already read [Nested braces and designated Initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888797/nested-braces-and-designated-initializers)

Used compilers:
`clang version 6.0.1` and `g++ (GCC) 8.2.1` Flags: `-std=c++20`

Can someone please explain which rule has to be fulfilled to get rid of all the errors and warnings? ( clang warns always of missing braces, but I can't find out where I should set additional ones which did not break gcc to compile ). Would be nice to get an example which could compile on gcc and clang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use:

```
Spur s1{ .kl = {{ {"XYZ"}, 1,2 }}};
Config c1{ "ABC", 1,2 , { .kl = std::nullopt }};
Signal si1{ {"ABC", 1,2 , { .kl = std::nullopt} }};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/m6Uw8P)

You need `{}` around `"XYZ"` to initialize base class.
(You might even add one more `{}` around to build `std::string` from `const char*` more explicitly :-) )

```
.kl = { { {"XYZ"}, 1,2 } }
      | | |
      | | v
      | | Base
      | v
      | KL
      v
      optional
```

Comment: Thanks! Also in "Signal" and "Config" if I use the ".kl=..."

Comment: `Signal` and `Config` have constructor, so cannot use designated initializer. To build `Spur` inside `Config`, you might do `Config c1{ "ABC", 1,2 , { .kl = {{ {"XYZ"}, 1,2 }} }};`